# how to get an array of unique key and associated value from multidimensional array with multiple keys and values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm firing a query on a particular table and getting this result :

```
        $results = array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["category"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["manufacturer"]=>
            string(1) "2"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["category"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["manufacturer"]=>
            string(1) "9"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["category"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["manufacturer"]=>
            string(2) "10"
          }
        }
```

I have tried many solutions like :

```
        $temp = array();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {               
                 $data = array_merge($temp[$key], $value);
            }
        }

    foreach ($results as $result) {
                foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                    array_push($temp[$result], $value);
                }
            }
```

I want the value of category as indexes of array and value of manufacturer as array of associated category (index). As shown below :

```
$array = array(1) {
[1]=> array(3) {
     2,9,10
     }
};
```

Comment: If possible, I would refactor the query to use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate the results you want. It will be easier than writing a control-break loop to process the results in the current format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live demo](https://eval.in/32985) of this code:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($results as $result){
    $temp[$result['category']][] = $result['manufacturer'];
}
```

Output is as requested:

```
array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "2"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "9"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "10"
    }
}
```

*Note: [All PHP arrays are associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so there's nothing you can do to get rid of the 0, 1, 2 indexes inside the array.*